# background-color not changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So it changes the background image, but not the background color.
Anyway care to point out the problem in my code?

JavaScript:

```
$("#menu a").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

CSS:

```
.hover {
    background-color: white;
    background-position: top center;
    background-image: url("img/dot.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the non-hover default class.

Comment: May be some other css rule is overriding it on the page.

Comment: You don't have to use `$.hover()`; you can do this in pure CSS using the `:hover` pseudo class.

Comment: You most probably have an issue with CSS definitions overriding each other - given you jQuery is correct...

Comment: hotfix - `background-color: white !important;`

Comment: Hotfix worked. Weird CSS overrule anyway, since background-color does come first. Thanks John.

Comment: @ChrisCates, don't use `!important` as a permanent fix. Figure out the specificity you need to override and use the minimal specificity necessary to get the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above... if you just add the following css, it will take care of it.

```
a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    background-position: top center;
    background-image: url("img/dot.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```

:hover is a pseudo css class, and you can use it on anything, without needing to add the jquery/js to support it.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark:

you need to make sure that the nodes exist in the DOM before binding events to them. If you're calling your `<script>` in the `<head>` wait for `document.ready`:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#menu a").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could be overriding the `background-color` property by using a selector with a [higher specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) elsewhere. If you've defined styles such as `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, `a:focus`, or `a:active` you will need a higher specificity selector to override it:

```
a.hover {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

You'll need to provide more of your CSS for us to give you better advice.

---

You may have misspelled an ID or not nested your `a` elements under another element with `[id="menu"]`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [ShankarSangoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772055/shankarsangoli)'s comment, you likely have another rule in your css that is overriding the background color, which in turn is likely a problem with [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

You can test this by changing your `hover` function slightly:

```
$("#menu a").hover(
    function () {
        //add 'background-color' as an inline css style which will have higher specificity than anything in the css.
        $(this).addClass("hover").css('background-color', 'white');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover").css('background-color', '');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that something overwrites your background color. Use firebug or another DOM inspector to find your problem. A hotfix is to make your background-color important but you should only use this for testing:

```
background-color: black !important;
```

If this works, you still need to find out what is overwriting your background.

Then you can do this with pure CSS

```
#menu a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    background-position: top center;
    background-image: url("img/dot_hover.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```